# How Grid Management Unit works in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying some experiments with the Hyper-Q property presents on devices C.C 3.5 and higher. I've found some information related to the hardware involved in this property. One of the units involved is the Grid Management Unit. According to this document http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf , this unit is able to dispatch and suspend grids. But my question is, What´s the policy developed by the Grid Management Unit to select the appropiated grid for execution?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A grid is all the threadblocks associated with a kernel launch.  In general, a grid will be selected for execution

1. in the order that it was received (i.e. in the order of kernel launches) < and >
2. When device resources necessary for the execution are available, < and >
3. in adherence with stream semantics

Suspension of grids *today* may occur under a limited set of circumstances:

1. [debugging](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html#single-gpu-debugging-with-desktop-manager-running) - to enable single GPU debug
2. [CUDA Dynamic Parallelism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#sm-id-and-warp-id)

The details of suspension of grids in CDP is not published, as far as I know, but the aim of the Grid Management Unit in this case is to

1. suspend kernels to free up resources for child kernels to execute (see above)
2. so that by executing (and clearing) child kernel launches, the parent kernels can then begin to make forward progress again.

This last necessity is due to the fact that unlike other concurrent kernel launches, which are typically independent of each other, there is an [implicit or explicit synchronization requirement](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#parent-and-child-grids) between the parent and the child kernel.